# Python json.loads doesn't work

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to figure out how to load JSON objects in Python.

```
   def do_POST(self):
    length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
    decData = str(self.rfile.read(length))
    print decData, type(decData)
    "{'name' : 'journal2'}" <type 'str'>
    postData = json.loads(decData)
    print postData, type(postData)
    #{'name' : 'journal2'} <type 'unicode'>
    postData = json.loads(postData)
    print postData, type(postData)
    # Error: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

Where am I going wrong?

**Error Code (JScript):**

```
var data = "{'name':'journal2'}";
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_request.open( "post", url, true );
http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
http_request.send(data);
```

**True Code (JScript):**

```
var data = '{"name":"journal2"}';
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_request.open( "post", url, true );
http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
http_request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**True Code (Python):**

```
   def do_POST(self):
    length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
    decData = self.rfile.read(length)
    postData = json.loads(decData)
    postData = json.loads(postData)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your JSON data is enclosed in extra quotes making it a JSON string, *and* the data contained within that string is *not* JSON.

Print `repr(decData)` instead, you'll get:

```
'"{\'name\' : \'journal2\'}"'
```

and the JSON library is correctly interpreting that as one string with the literal contents `{'name' : 'journal2'}`. If you stripped the outer quotes, the contained characters are not valid JSON, because JSON strings must always be enclosed in double quotes.

For all the `json` module is concerned, `decData` could just as well have contained `"This is not JSON"` and `postData` would have been set to `u'This is not JSON'`.

```
>>> import json
>>> decData = '''"{'name' : 'journal2'}"'''
>>> json.loads(decData)
u"{'name' : 'journal2'}"
>>> json.loads(json.loads(decData))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Fix whatever is producing this string, your view is fine, it's the input that is broken.

Answer (score 5):

To workaround the error 'Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes' you can do:

```
import json
data = "{'name' : 'journal2'}"
json.loads(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: this is not right, `eval(data)` may get the right result

Comment: That's true but you shouldn't use eval() I think that is the idea of using json module. Use eval is considered a bad practice, I this is an interesting answer about it http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/2289246

Answer (score -3):

You can also go with `eval`:

```
data = "{'name' : 'test'}"
eval(data)
```

It works and returns you a dict.

Comment: Judging from the accepted answer, you are starting at the wrong point (you'd need `data  = '''"{'name' : 'journal2'}"'''` to accurately represent what the OP is given), which probably means the `eval` is less helpful.